# Match users with sufficient experience with a skill to a project's requirements

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables - `profiles`, `projects` (parent) and `requirements` (child):

The `profiles` table includes columns to track a user's traits e.g.

| user_id | country_id | language_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 17 | 33 |
| 2 | 75 | 89 |

The `requirements` table contains the user criteria for a `project` e.g.

| project_id | filter | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | country_id | 17 |
| 1 | language_id | 33 |
| 1 | language_id | 89 |

When a user logs in, I need to show them all projects for which they satisfy the requirements.

The query also needs to take into account the fact that some projects, such as in the example above, may include a particular filter (language_id) more than once. In these instances, the query should use `OR` instead of `AND`. So, the above example, might be something like this:

```sql
WHERE country_id = 17 AND (language_id = 33 OR language_id = 89)
```

There are around 20 filters in total, so using `joins` for each shouldn't be a problem in terms of performance.

How would I go about doing this? Cross-joins? Relational division?

Thanks!

**Edit**: Using the above data, user #1 would see project #1 because they match on `country_id` and `language_id`. User #2 would not see project #1 because they do not match on `country_id`

Comment: Please show clear expected output here based on your sample data.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add it. It's there now.

Comment: Inner joins would do.

Comment: Would you mind including an example please?

Comment: [I'm a slower answerer, so this goes in a fiddle instead](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bfd200/10)

Comment: Thanks @Scratte! Just to confirm, does your example also take into account the 'OR' requirement I mentioned in the original post?

Comment: @Matt Consider playing about with the queries to the point where you truly understand what's going on :) You'll see that the queries are no different from that of the accepted Answer. Your "OR" requirement is fulfilled since it's represented as different records in the `requirements` table. Only one of those records need to match to be consistent with an "OR".

Comment: Will do. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using inner joins to find projects for the user

```
-- sample data
with requirements(project_id, filter, value) as (
  select 1, 'country_id',  17 union all
  select 1, 'language_id', 33 union all
  select 1, 'language_id', 89),
profiles(user_id, country_id, language_id) as (
  select 1, 17, 33 union all
  select 2, 75, 89
)
-- the query
select distinct t1.project_id 
from profiles p
join requirements t1 on t1.filter = 'country_id' and t1.value = p.country_id
join requirements t2 on t2.filter = 'language_id' and t2.value = p.language_id
where p.user_id = 1
```

It kind of ANDs every requirement matching any (OR) allowed value. It fails only when there exists a requirement so that a user has no any of requried values of the requiement.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=86c76ce0fcee62a383f26d7f6ef079f9)

Comment: Thank you for adding an example, but how would this work as a general query? By which I mean, without all the hard number references.

Comment: @Scratte,  It kind of ANDs every requiremet matching any (OR) allowed value.   It fails only there exists a requiement so that a user has no any of requried values of the  requiement .

Comment: @Serg I understands how it works myself. I meant to explain to everyone how to works in the post itself. I was about to post an Answer with explanations when your Answer came in.

Comment: @Scratte, I'd love to see your answer too if you wouldn't mind sharing? Thanks!

Comment: @Serg how would this work as a general query? By which I mean, without all the hard number references.

Comment: @Matt, anyway, you have a fixed number of columns in Profiles. So there's the fixed number of joins. Only user_id is variable parameter of the query

Comment: @Matt It wasn't entire finished, but it's there in a comment on your Question. It still needed the project_ids, but the actual queries are no different than this Answer. There are no "hard number references" on this post. The initial `WITH` is just a way to get the tables defined.

Comment: @Serg . . . I am guessing the `select distinct` is not needed.  I am guessing that the `filter`/`value` combination is unique in the `requirements` table, even though `filter` values can be duplicated.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, most probably you're right. It's just a precaution as SO doesn't prohibit  multiple values explicitly. So this case could be allowed as well https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5c016719125a28d7f8d221540a659b3e

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with just 1 join and a conditional expression in the `ON` clause.
Then with aggregation you filter out all the projects that do not satisfy both conditions for a user:

```
SELECT r.project_id
FROM requirements r INNER JOIN profiles p
ON r.value = CASE r.filter
  WHEN 'country_id' THEN p.country_id
  WHEN 'language_id'THEN p.language_id
END
WHERE p.user_id = ?
GROUP BY r.project_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 -- number of requirements the user must satisfy
```

Replace `?` with the `user_id` that you search for.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=31443cb2b7910194fd4c4b9746d092c1).

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for sharing, but a quick question about the use of CASE. Would that cause a performance issue at scale? Not suggesting it would, I honestly don't know...

Comment: @Matt of course it would not be as good as a simple join, but for your case you need more than a simple join. This way you avoid joining requirements multiple times.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will test both options and see what the results are.